# Neo4J - CQL - How to match exactly this pattern?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4J graph database.

I have two node labels :

- :Person (users)
- :Event (events created by users : with the place, startDate, guests, ...)

And 2 relationships types :

- :IS_INVITED_TO
- :IS_INVITED_BY

To keep it simple, i have simplified the query to the minimum.

Here is the query :

```
MATCH (user:Person {guid: $userGuid})-[:IS_INVITED_TO]->(event:Event) 
WITH user, event 

MATCH (event)<-[:IS_INVITED_TO]-(user)-[:IS_INVITED_BY]->(invitor:Person) 
WITH user, event, collect(invitor) AS invitors 

RETURN {properties: properties(event), invite_by_nodes: invitors};
```

I want to find all events where current user is invited (line 1 : works fine).

For each event, i want to know who invited me (line 3 : doesn't works, it returns invitors that invited me to other events, not the current one).

I'm pretty sure that pattern of the line 3 is incorrect :
It finds (user), but ignores (event). So, the query returns all invitors that invited me for an event (not the current event).

I also tried loooooot of things before to post (3 days lost..) :

- UNWIND collect(event) AS event (after the first MATCH & WITH) : to work with the current event iteration
- Add WHERE clauses to force to find current event
- I've searched everywhere on Neo4J's documentation / stackoverflow

Help will be very appreciated !
Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: With just a schema like that `(user)-[:IS_INVITED_BY]->(r:Person)` I don't see how you can link the `IS_INVITED_BY` with the event ...

Comment: @logisima
I've also tried this schema : 
`(event)<-[:IS_INVITED_TO]-(user)-[:IS_INVITED_BY]->(invitor:Person)-[:CREATOR|IS_INVITED_TO]->(event)`


I didn't post it to keep simplicity.

This way i can link `IS_INVITED_BY` with the event ?

Comment: Nop... your event is shared with many user, so you don't know for who the link `IS_INVITED_BY` is for !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your project, it seems that the invitation is something important, so it must be a node.

Your model should be :

```
(:User)-[:HAS_INVITATION]->(i:Invitation)-[:FOR_EVENT]->(:Event),
(i:Invitation)-[:COMES_FROM]->(:User)
```

So your query will become :

```
MATCH 
  (user:User {guid: $userGuid})[:HAS_INVITATION]->(i:Invitation),
  (i)-[:COMES_FROM]->(invitor:User),
  (i)-[:FOR_EVENT]->(e:Event)
RETURN e, invitor
```

Comment: I must change my schema in order to test. I'll keep you informed and will mark as resolved if it is. Thank you ;-)
If someone else have another solution ?

Comment: This is a good solution, by having this intermediate node it preserves the context of the inviter, invitee, and the event in question, which was missing from the original model (no clear context/relationship between the inviter and the event).

Comment: this model works perfectly !
Thanks, and merry christmas :-)